# HTML document scrolls to the iframe element in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, scroll

I am using jWYSIWYG - jQuery Rich Text Editor. Here is the link to it :[jWYSIWYG RTE](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg)

It is based on textarea and an iframe is created with domready event. The problem is that my html page scrolls to RTE(Rich text editor) every time it is opened but only in Chrome browser. All other browsers open the page at the top of it. js file of this RTE has 2300 lines and it is very difficult for me to find the code causing it because I am new to javascript. My question is what code could cause this cind of behaviour? Pleas help me to find it. Thanks for replies.